# Add-ClusterVirtualMachineRole generates an extra report line

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2012

A 3rd party contractor built our sister sites Windows 2012 Hyper-V hosts and they appear to have enabled some setting on one of them that generates an extra report when the following cluster PowerShell command is run:

> [void](Add-ClusterVirtualMachineRole -VirtualMachine $Name)

Run this command on the other hosts and no output is generated. On the 5th Hyper-V host, a status line like this is returned:

> Report file location: C:\Windows\cluster\Reports\Highly Available
>   Virtual Machine c0ad15c2-7060-4cc7-a881-50b4419a290f on 2014.02.25 At
>   18.37.23.mht

It's a minor annoyance but anyone any idea how this has been turned on? So one can turn it off?

Answer (score 0):

Just shows what happens when you discuss said problem with a colleague - he suggested that maybe that's an *error* report. I hadn't actually thought to look at the report! It is indeed a warning that this 5th Hyper-V host has it's default storage path defined as a folder that is not in clustered storage. C:\VMs instead of C:\Cluster Storage. Reconfigure the Hyper-V host storage folder and the report goes away.

Would have been better if it had said "WARNING report"